# UnsatisfiedLinkError while adding library

Tags: java, android, unsatisfiedlinkerror, android-augmented-reality

I am trying to add [this](https://github.com/kudan-eu/Public-Samples-Android) library and on running the application, however when Intent is fired to start `Markerless_Wall` activity, following error is shown:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mproga1nagindergupta.kundan_public-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.mproga1nagindergupta.kundan_public-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libKudan.so"
                                                    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                    at eu.kudan.kudan.ARFragment.<clinit>(ARFragment.java:28)
                                                    at eu.kudan.kudan.ARActivity.onCreate(ARActivity.java:35)
                                                    at com.example.mproga1nagindergupta.kundan_public.Markerless_Wall.onCreate(Markerless_Wall.java:41)
                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
```

Comment: Instructions:

    Download the Kudan AR Android SDK here: https://www.kudan.eu/download-kudan-ar-sdk/
    Import the .aar package to your project by going to (File -> New -> New Module...) and selecting Import .JAR/.AAR package.
    Go to (File -> Project Structure...), select your app module, click the dependencies tab, click the plus in the lower left and select Module Dependancy to add KudanAR as a dependancy to your project.

Comment: tried.. not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521836/how-to-add-classpath-in-an-android-studio-project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936254/how-to-set-the-class-path-in-eclipse-and-android-studio

Comment: two ways to set classpath