# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: DataBinderMapper

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, android-databinding

I just integrated [this](https://github.com/skedgo/DateTimeRangePicker) library and when I run the application, I got this error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/databinding/DataBinderMapper;
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.databinding.DataBinderMapper" on path: DexPathList[ ...
```

I haven't enabled data binding in my app's module. Should I enable it?
Library also uses Kotlin. Is that the cause?

Answer (score -1):

Include the library at your Runtime classpath.

you can do something like this:

```
java -cp "Test.jar;lib/*" my.package.MainClass
```

Or if you are using tomcat, then add it at tomcat classpath: go though this link [Including external jar in Tomcat ClassPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163447/including-external-jar-in-tomcat-classpath?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: What should I write there?

Comment: I am using Android Studio and this is an Android app project.

Comment: you can Go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936254/how-to-set-the-class-path-in-eclipse-and-android-studio, it may help